# How to properly use JSExport methods in a JSExportTopLevel object in Scala.js from a <script> tag?

Tags: scala, scala.js

I have some sjs code:

```
@JSExportTopLevel("CCRS")
object JsApi {

  @JSExport
  def makeJobId: JobId = JobId()
  // ...
}
```

I have the following `<body>` element, which I'll note is properly finding the sjs-generated `.js` files since I was using a 3rd party SPA framework previously - though the launcher for that is now commented out:

```
<body>
<script type="application/javascript" src="ace/ace.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="target/web-client-jsdeps.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="target/web-client-opt.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="target/web-client-launcher.js"></script> -->
<input type="text"
       placeholder="Enter a command:"
       value="pwd"
       onkeydown="oneShotHandler()" />
<div id="one-shot-demo"></div>
<script type="application/javascript">
  var oneShotId = CCRS.makeJobId();
</script>
</body>
```

Upon page load, I get the following error: `TypeError: CCRS.makeJobId is not a function`.

Not really sure what I should be looking for in the generated `web-client-opt.js` file (using sjs 0.6.22 currently, with `-P:scalajs:sjsDefinedByDefault`). But, I do see this line, which I believe should be doing the export:

```
$e.CCRS = $m_Lorg_xsede_jobrunner_client_JsApi$();
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized this just as I was finishing typing my question. The beauty of talking it out.

In Scala.js, I needed to add the `()` to my method:

```
  @JSExport
  def makeJobId(): JobId = JobId()
```